# How to send email from WordPress (contact forms) in Docker container?

Tags: wordpress, docker, smtp, phpmailer, sendmail

I have a little issue with Wordpress image, will be thankful for any help.

I have existing database, which I import  with dump.

My Mysql Dockerfile listing below:

```
FROM mariadb:10.1.20

COPY dump/dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD pass

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

This is Wordpress Dockerfile, here I import my wp-content folder from src directory:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

COPY ./src /var/www/html

ENV WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD pass
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_NAME db
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_HOST mysql:3306
```

And of course docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    build: mysql/
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: mysql
  vshvetsov:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: wordpress/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: always
    container_name: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

When I use plugin Contact Form 7 i've got an error with sending email after click button and of course don't get this message in my mailbox.

The only thing what I've found is this message:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2017:13:52:42 +0000] "POST /const HTTP/1.1" 200 879 "http://localhost:8000/contacts" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
sh: 1: -t: not found
```

I've tried to install sendmail, but it still didn't help.

Thank you all for help.

I saw [this issue](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/30), but it's not fixed at this moment.

Comment: I hope this comment will help somehow : https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/135#issuecomment-277199026

Comment: any news about this ?

Comment: Any news? it is a very typical question about docker + wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You can install ssmtp, as in :
https://github.com/xgodon/RIG/blob/master/dockerized-apps/wordpress/Dockerfile

you just need a ssmtp.conf file like

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=xxx@mail.com
AuthPass=
UseSTARTTLS=YES
# Allow the "From" email header.
FromLineOverride=YES
```

there is a delay (beacause no qualified host name)  in the sending but here is the solution :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sendmail-is-slow-to-send-mail

i'll update the Dockerfile soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the sendmail daemon.

The entrypoint `docker-entrypoint.sh` set in the image expects specific arguments. I was able to solve my issue by wrapping the original entrypoint and starting the sendmail daemon.

I have commented on the following thread:

https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/30#issuecomment-1483961348

> wrapped-entrypoint.sh
>
> ```bash
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # Start the sendmail daemon
> /usr/sbin/sendmail -bd
>
> # Execute the original entrypoint script
> exec docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
> ```
>
> Dockerfile
>
> ```
> FROM docker.io/library/wordpress:php7.4-apache
>
> # Install sendmail
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sendmail && apt-get clean
>
> # Copy the wrapped entrypoint script
> COPY wrapped-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
>
> # Make the script executable
> RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wrapped-entrypoint.sh
>
> # Use the wrapped entrypoint
> ENTRYPOINT ["wrapped-entrypoint.sh"]
> ```